# combining two regression lines drawn from different datasets

Tags: r

I have a 2 different datasets. I plotted two of their regreesion lines. I need to show these two in the same regression plot. How can I do?

`reg1 <- lm(a~b,data1)
reg2 <-lm(a~b,data2)`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an "empty" plot with `type="n"` and then add your regression lines with `abline`

```
df <- mtcars

reg1 <- lm(mpg~cyl,mtcars)
reg2 <-lm(disp~hp,mtcars)
plot(c(0,0),c(0,60),type="n")        
abline(reg1)
abline(reg2)
```

you also can add points with `points` if you want. Then you also don't need to make the empty plot before, since it's "normal" plotting and then just adding ablines.

Comment: but, my regression is same but datas are different. Will your command work for it?

Comment: @TFB i don't understand this question. If the regression is the same, you don't need to combine it since the lines will be identical. The data i used on this example is also different. I used `mpg~cyl` at the first regression and `disp~hp` on the second. So completely different data. Since you did not inserted data, i used the mtcar dataset. So if you run my code and that's what you wanted, you just have to remodel it for your case

Comment: okay understandable. Thanks. One more question: I plotted it, commands worked. But there is no line in the graph. Why that might be?

Comment: @TFB did you got the dimensions of the plot correctly? You got to adjust the range of your frame. The invisible points c(0,0) and c(0,60) are making this. You could the something like: `plot(c(0,0),c(0,max(a,b)),type="n")`

Comment: It also fixed,  but I think we should put something between `abline` commands. because I got eror like: `Error: unexpected symbol in:
"abline(reg1) 
abline"`

Comment: @TFB this ist normaly more a spelling error message.

Comment: Got it, do you think that there is a way of doing it with using `geom_smooth`

Comment: @TFB well, since i don't have context why you are using geom_smooth now, i have no idea :D but if my answer helped you sufficiently, you can mark it as accepted answer by pressing the check on the answer on the top left corner of the answer

Comment: Thank you however it did not work suffciently actually, when I plot the graph, I do not have dots but I have the line.

Comment: @TFB i wrote that literally in the answer, that i just plot the lines and how to do it if you want to keep the points. If you want the dots just do `plot(x_1,y_1)` do `points(x_2,y_2)` and add both lines